# Display Parent-Child data in Table

Tags: php, html, css, list, html-table

I fetched some data from mysql I need to display the data in table-tree format but its isn't working. However I tried to display it with the help of list but actually a table format is required.

```
<?php
session_start();
    include 'dbconn.php';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
    mysql_select_db('cms');
    //select all rows from the main_menu table
    $result = mysql_query("select id, label as title, parent as parentid,link from pages");

    //create a multidimensional array to hold a list of menu and parent menu
    $menu = array(
        'menus' => array(),
        'parent_menus' => array(),

    );

    //build the array lists with data from the menu table
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //creates entry into menus array with current menu id ie. $menus['menus'][1]
        $menu['menus'][$row['id']] = $row;
        //creates entry into parent_menus array. parent_menus array contains a list of all menus with children
        $menu['parent_menus'][$row['parentid']][] = $row['id'];
    }

    // Create the main function to build milti-level menu. It is a recursive function.  
    function buildMenu($parent, $menu) {
    $html = "";
    $char=" ";
    if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$parent])) {
        foreach ($menu['parent_menus'][$parent] as $menu_id) {
            if (!isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                $html .= "<li>".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['title']."</li>";
            }
            if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                $html .= "<li>".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['title'];
                $html .= "<ul>";
                $html .= buildMenu($menu_id, $menu);
                $html .= "</ul>";
                $html .= "</li>";
            }
        }
    }
    return $html;
    }
    echo buildMenu(0, $menu);
    ?>
```

the output that I get is:

[image: This is the output I get]

I have modified the buildMenu function a bit: I need the indenting in the table what I get is just a column

```
function buildMenu($parent, $menu) {
    $html = "";
    $char=" ";
    $html.="<table border='3px'>";
    if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$parent])) {
        foreach ($menu['parent_menus'][$parent] as $menu_id) {
            if (!isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                $html .= "<tr><td>".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['title']."</td></tr>";
            }
            if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                $html .= "<tr><td>".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['title'];
                $html .= "<tr><td>";
                $html .= buildMenu($menu_id, $menu);
                $html .= "</td></tr>";
                $html .= "</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
        $html.="</table>";
    return $html;
}
```

and getting the output as:

[image]

My Aim is to get such structure:

[image]

Comment: what is wrong with the output you are getting? is it just visual apperance that bothers you? it seems to be a correct representation of the data

Comment: sir actually yes, what I need is the table that I get to b displayed in an indented fashion, which is what i am not able to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your efforts:

Here is the code what I was expecting

My Final buildMenu function:

```
echo $html="<table class='test2'><tr data-tt-id='0'><td>Root</td></tr>";

function buildMenu($parent, $menu) {
    $char=" ";
    if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$parent])) {



   foreach ($menu['parent_menus'][$parent] as $menu_id) {
            //echo "id:".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id']."par:".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid'];
            if (!isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                $html .= "<tr data-tt-id='".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id']."' data-tt-parent-id='".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid']."'><td>".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['title']."</td></tr>";
            }
            if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                $html .= "<tr data-tt-id='".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id']."' data-tt-parent-id='".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid']."'><td>".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['title'];
                $html .= "<td>";
                $html .= buildMenu($menu_id, $menu);
                $html .= "</td>";
                $html .= "</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

echo buildMenu(0, $menu);
echo "</table>";
```

Final Result: 1:Collapsed Tree     2:Expanded Tree

[image: Collapsed Tree]

[image: Expanded Tree]

Hope this helps if someone is facing same issue.

And yes for the TreeTable I used a Github Plugin [Github: TreeTable Plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/treetable/)

Answer (score 0):

Well if its just looks then style the table accordingly to get your indentation right, for example

```
td {padding-left:10px}
```

I believe the "correct" way semanticly would be to do this the bullet-list style (as your first example), and remove the bullets and style as you wish

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```